# Help with C# - Silverlight - ToolKit - Dynamic Line Series

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, toolkit, linechart

I need help with line chart in Silverlight Toolkit Line Series that updates dynamically having 3 lines updating itself every 5 seconds how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

A good example of Code is :
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/161397/365415.aspx

You set your 3 Series with Observable Collections which are Dependency Propertys.

And you bind your XAML Series Items Source to your Dependency Propertys.

You then will need to create a Timer that after 5 seconds will set off a Event which will go and update the DataSeries Dependency Propertys.
The Data will automatically bind the Line Series.

Thanks